# How to communicate between two google chrome extensions launched in two different instances of the browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, localhost, communication

I have a requirement to use two different instances of a google chrome browser and then establish the communication between two different extensions in the respective instances.

In order to have different instances of the google chrome browser I launch the chrome's executable with two different shortcuts. Here is an example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\User\Desktop\temp1"

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
--user-data-dir="C:\Users\User\Desktop\temp2"
```

For testing purposes, I have written two extensions.
First is the receiver and the second one is the sender. Please examine the following source codes.

First extension:

```
/* Extension1/manifest.json */ 

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension 1 receiver test",
  "description": "This is the main extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
} 


/* Extension1/background.js */ 

// request listener:
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.testPassed) {
      console.log('Test passed: '+request.testPassed);
    }
  });
```

Second extension:

```
/* Extension2/manifest.json */ 

{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Extension 2 sender test",
  "description": "This is the secondary extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  }
}


/* Extension2/background.js */ 

// The ID of the 1st extension.
var laserExtensionId = "dnclcmbindlbmocdmjdeiecjffbobljc";

// Make a simple request:
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(laserExtensionId, {testPassed: true});
```

The above code works if both extensions are loaded in the same browser, but it does not in two different instances of the browser.

Note: I have tried adding "externally_connectable" line to my manifest files to allow external communication, but none of these parameters seemed to produce any effect:

```
"externally_connectable": {
  "ids": ["*"]
}

"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["chrome-extension://insermyextensionidhereplease/*"]
}

"externally_connectable": {
  "matches": ["*://127.0.0.1/*"]
}
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Comment: You'll have to write a mediator utility and use nativeMessaging API.

Comment: Can you please give me some more clues? I don't have any experience with that type of applications.

Comment: To answer your question: "No, nobody is knows how to make the way that you are trying to do this work, because it won't work that way."